# Katalon command not working in KatalonStudio docker image in CircleCI. How to make it work?

Tags: circleci, katalon-studio

I used below image inside CircleCI config:

```
katalonstudio/katalon-circleci
```

Next, I used below command to launch the script execution.

```
katalon -noSplash  -runMode=console -consoleLog -noExit - 
projectPath="XYZProject.prj" -retry=2 -retryFailedTestCases=true - 
testSuitePath="Test Suites/SmokeTest" -executionProfile="default" - 
browserType="Chrome"
```

I am getting below error in cirlceCI.

```
katalon: command not found
```

Can anyone please help how to run the test script?

Answer (score 0):

you need to run the command inside the folder where you have the katalon.exe

ex: `D:\Katalon_Studio_Windows_64-5.8.3>katalon -runMode=console...`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is Docker based; you need to have a .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
# The docker image which is used to run test suites is provided by katalon studio:
# https://github.com/katalon-studio/docker-images 

metro-web-verify-content-chrome:
  image: katalonstudio/katalon-circleci
  tags:
  - qa
  - test
  script:
  - export KATALON_OPTS='-browserType="Chrome" -retry=0 retryFailedTestCases=true -executionProfile="default" -statusDelay=15 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/SmokeTest"'
  - $KATALON_KATALON_CIRCLECI_ROOT_DIR/scripts/katalon-execute.sh
```